# Using one Service Provider for multiple Websites

Tags: authentication, configuration, shibboleth, service-provider

I have deployed two application on IIS. The first is called `site1`for instance and the second one is `site2`

Configuring a shibboleth authentication for one of them works fine. However I have been looking for a way to register both of them so that the service provider will send both sites to the same Identity Provider and authenticate with.

I think this section in the documentations describes the same scenario, https://wiki.cac.washington.edu/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=28939166 I am looking for.

My `Shibboleth2.xml` file looks like this:

```
<InProcess logger="native.logger">
    <ISAPI normalizeRequest="true" safeHeaderNames="true">

        <Site id="1" name="site1"/>
        <Site id="2" name="site2"/>
    </ISAPI>
</InProcess>
<RequestMapper type="Native">
    <RequestMap applicationId="default">
        <Host name="site1" applicationId="OCMS" scheme="https" authType="shibboleth" requireSession="true" />
        <Host name="site2"  scheme="https" authType="shibboleth" requireSession="true" />
    </RequestMap>
</RequestMapper>

<ApplicationDefaults REMOTE_USER="eppn" entityID="https://site2/shibboleth">


    <ApplicationOverride id="OCMS" entityID="https://site1/Shibboleth"/>
</ApplicationDefaults>
```

I have deleted some elements just to make it clear.

I am trying to authenticate using TestShib. I have registered both site by uploading their Metadata files and still getting the error: `Error Message: SAML 2 SSO profile is not configured for relying party https://site1`

Hoever site2 is working

Comment: which error are you getting?

Comment: I am sorry. just forgot

Error Message: SAML 2 SSO profile is not configured for relying party https://site1

Site2 works as expected

Comment: I'm having difficultly using my service provider. I can test it locally with simple curl requests to localhost:80/Shibboleth.sso/Status and localhost:80/secure, but I'm not sure how I can use this service provider if apache is only available to the local host. Can someone explain how you can actually use your service provider once it's set up?